# Cannot find symbol in java, both .java files are in the same directory when compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath, javac, symbols

I have 2 files, tweet.java and Account.java. When I compile tweet.java it's goes through but when I compile Account.java it says this error

```
C:\Users\Nolan\Documents\OBJECTP\Java\tweet>javac tweet.java

C:\Users\Nolan\Documents\OBJECTP\Java\tweet>javac Account.java
Account.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    private tweet[] UserTweets;
            ^
symbol:   class tweet
location: class Account
Account.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private final tweet[] EMPTY_TWEET;
                  ^
symbol:   class tweet
location: class Account
Account.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    this.UserTweets = new tweet[20];
                          ^
symbol:   class tweet
location: class Account
Account.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    this.EMPTY_TWEET = new tweet[0];
                           ^
symbol:   class tweet
location: class Account
Account.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            this.UserTweets[TweetCount] = new tweet(message);
                                              ^
symbol:   class tweet
location: class Account
5 errors
```

I've asked my professor and alot of friends and they don't know what's the problem is! I'm on the edge here because I have to result to using compiler's from my university's lab (apparently it works there when I compile it).

I'll cut the methods in the source codes to shorten it.

tweet.java file:

```
 //tweet.java
 import java.util.Calendar;

public class tweet {

    private String message;
    private int D;
    private int M;
    private int Y;
    private int H;
    private Calendar now;
    private int Min;

    public tweet(String Mes){
        this.message=Mes;
        this.now=Calendar.getInstance();
        this.D=now.get(Calendar.DATE)+1;
        this.M=now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        this.Y=now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.H=now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        this.Min=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }
    //Method's here
}
```

Account.java file:

```
//Account.java file
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Account {

    private String Username;
    private String Password;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private tweet[] UserTweets;
    private int TweetCount;
    private final tweet[] EMPTY_TWEET;

    public Account(String UserName,String Password,String FName,String LName){
        this.Username=UserName;
        this.Password=Password;
        this.FirstName=FName;
        this.LastName=LName;
        this.UserTweets = new tweet[20];
        this.EMPTY_TWEET = new tweet[0];
        this.TweetCount=0;
    }
//Method's here
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: This should work. Do you have package declarations in your classes by any chance?

Comment: I have executed your commands and I have no problem. Your `tweet` class is at the root of your project and not in another package ?

Comment: Edit: I've tried adding package declarations and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have put them in the same directory,the two classes are not accessible to each other.You need to import tweet in Account class or better create a package and put both of the classes in them.

**package com**

import java.util.Calendar;

public class tweet {
///

}

**package com**

//Account.java file

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Account {

//

}

Avoiding using putting your classes in default package for better namespace

Comment: I've tried creating a package, it didn't work though.----

package twitter;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Account { // code }-----did that on both source files.